# Using Goerly Testnet for development requires 0.001eth in wallet

Tags: ether, testnets, goerli, faucets

Using Goerly Testnet for development requires 0.001eth already existing in the wallet.

I tried alchemy's and quicknode's sites but same requirement.

Which faucet should i use for my first O.OO1 eth because i don't have any :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are many faucets for Goerli, as people are shifting to sepolia, but you can try out the pow faucet https://goerli-faucet.pk910.de/

Apart from this, you can ask for some goerli eth in the community groups, maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 4):

Plenty of Goerli & Sepolia on the [Chainstack faucet](https://faucet.chainstack.com/). It drips too to keep your address with Goerli ETH and Sepolia ETH, so you don't run out or have to re-request.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer. So i switch to Sepolia actually.